# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__

Tags: python, runtime-error

Working on a project to get headword from a sentence using Collins Head Rules.

This is the error that I get:

```
File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Python27\PyProject\src\Feature\FeatureExtractor.py", line 225, in collinsHeadExtractor
    if raw['whWord']=='whWord-what':
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is the part of the code that generated the error:

```
def whoPattern(question):
            p1 = re.compile("^[w|W]ho (is|are|was|were)( the)*( \`\`)*( [A-Z][a-z]+)+( \'\')* \?$")
            if p1.match(question):
                return "HUM:desc"
            p2 = re.compile("^[w|W]ho (is|was) .*")
            if p2.match(question):
                return "Hum:ind"
        if training:
            file = DBStore.trainingRoot+"\\headword_question"+colName+".txt"
        else:
            file = DBStore.testingRoot+"\\headword_question"+colName+".txt"
        f = open(file,'r')
        p = re.compile(r"(?P<head>.+)::(?P<question>.+)")
        i = 0
        rawQuestions = DBStore.getDB()['raw'+colName]
        p2 = re.compile('\.')
        headWord = []
        for line in f:
            print iWor
            i = i + 1
            match = p.match(line)
            print match.group('question')
            head = p2.sub('',match.group('head'))
            question = match.group('question')
            raw = rawQuestions.find_one({'question':question})
            if raw['whWord']=='whWord-what':
                pattern = whatPattern(question)
            elif raw['whWord']=='whWord-who':
                pattern = whoPattern(question)
            else:
                pattern = None
            if head.isupper() and (pattern == "DESC:def_1" or pattern == 'DESC:def_2'):
                pattern = "ABBR:exp"
            if head == 'null':
                headWord = [None,pattern]
            elif pattern is None:
                headWord = [head,pattern]
            else:
                headWord = [None,pattern]
            rawQuestions.update({'question':question},{"$set":{"head":headWord}},safe=True,multi=True)
```

Any help to figure this out would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This means that `rawQuestions.find_one({'question':question})` has returned `None`.